# Unrecognized name: clientId BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL and i'm try to make a query:

```
SELECT
  clientId,
  pagePath,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN isExit IS NOT NULL THEN last_interaction
    ELSE
    nextTime
  END
    ) AS time_on_page
FROM (
  SELECT
    hits.page.pagePath,
    hits.isExit,
    hits.time/1000 AS hits_time,
    LEAD(hits.time/1000, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitid ORDER BY hits.time ASC) AS nextTime,
    MAX(
    IF
      (hits.isInteraction = TRUE,
        hits.time / 1000,
        0)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitid) AS last_interaction
  FROM
    `merck-bigquery.1===.ga_sessions_20201231`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.type = "PAGE"
    AND hits.page.hostname = 'www.msdmed.ru' )
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 ASC
```

The BigQuery returns an error Unrecognized name: clientId
I dont understand what's wrong in this query, because clientId its default field in BQ schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer query can see only fields listed in the inner query. Try removing `clientId` from outer one or adding `clientId` explicitly into the inner query.

Comment: I tried it 
`SELECT
  clientId,
  trafficSource,
  pagePath,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN isExit IS NOT NULL THEN last_interaction
    ELSE
    nextTime
  END
    ) AS time_on_page,
FROM (
  SELECT
    clientId,
    trafficSource,
    hits.page.pagePath,
  `
But i got the error select list expression references column trafficSource which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:5]

Comment: Ok, now the outer query sees the clientId from the inner query. Now the issue is that the outer query has an aggregation function `SUM` and a `GROUP BY`. It expects that all selected fields (`clientId` and `pagePath`) should be listed inside 'GROUP BY'. Try replacing `GROUP BY  1` with `GROUP BY 1, 2`